Write a program that takes an input value n and then finds the first n primes
Recap, partly for fun and partly as a hobby I am trying to learn as much C++ as possible. And to do so I am trying to read the excellent text "Programming: Principles and Practice Using C++".
As is known, the text at the end of each chapter presents exercises. Since many of these are anything but easy (at least for me). When I think I have found a good solution, the satisfaction is so high that I feel like sharing my work.
Referring to one in chapter 4, number 15, that is:

Write a program that takes an input value n and then finds the first n
primes.

I wrote the following:
int main()
{
    //Chapter 4 - Excercises - 15)

    cout << "Give me a value n and I'll find you first n primes: ";
    int n{ 0 };
    cin >> n;
    bool control{ true };

    int a{ 0 };

    for (int i = 2; a < n; ++i)
    {
        control = true;
        for (int x = 2; x < i; x++)
        {
            if (i % x == 0 && i != 2)
            {
                control = false;
            }
        }
        if (control)
        {
            cout << i << ' ';
            ++a;
        }
    }
}                                                                                         

Maybe someone is s facing the same exercises and wants to share their work or maybe just to have a cue or a different idea, it could be of some use.

When the outer for() sets i = 2, then the internal for() gets skipped entirely – it starts from x = 2 which immediately makes x < i false. And then i gets incremented, so it's never equal 2 again. As a result, the second half of the condition if (i % x == 0 && i != 2) is unnecessary.

You're missing some definitions (e.g. I'm guessing cin is an alias for std::cin from <iostream>).  It's best to present complete code if you possibly can; that generally earns you good reviews.

you're right I forgot to write which header files were used (iostream, vector etc) and above all the use of the std namespace.
In reality the book indicates to use a header file called std_lib_facilities.h which includes all the header files needed to follow the text of the entire book.
In any case you are absolutely right I should have indicated it.
Also the observation above is correct, in the if inside the for i !=2 is superfluous. I must have remained there after a revision of the previous code @@. Sometimes it seems like I'm going crazy making these redundant loops.

The first review remark, addressing the context, is that while this program is technically valid C++, it is factually rather idiomatic 1980s C (when linkers could not handle symbols with names longer than 6 chars ;-) ).

At the very least use readable variable names. https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7daf2fb12602eaa3 (oh and adds input validation)

Algorithm:
A better algorithm has been known for several millennia.
Sieve of Eratosthenes.
One of the biggest things in programming is picking the correct/optimal algorithm. Note: Sieve is generally considered better (for a broad definition of general). If it is quicker, it will depend on what you expect the value of n to be, etc. If you know that the loop method is going to be quicker because you have an understanding of the context under which this application is going to be used, that is something that should be noted in the comments.
Design
Split your code into functions that are logical and can be independently reviewed and improved.
Optimizations
We know that primes are only divisible by themselves and one. So you are using the basic method of checking if any smaller number divides into this value. That's a bit overkill.

You only need to check up to the square root of the number. Anything larger  will already have been hit by a smaller number.
Consider 12; it has the following factors:
     1  * 12
     2  *  6
     3  *  4
     -------- Now they repeat: Note this line is sqrt(12) * sqrt(12)
     4  *  3
     6  *  2
     12 *  1

Notice that the factors repeat: for every small one there is a big one. So you only need to find the small one in the pair. If it does not have a small one then you it will not have a big value.
So you can exit your loop at the sqrt(i).

You only need to check lower primes (not all the numbers). If the candidate number is divisible by a lower number "a" that is not a prime; then "a" is divisible by a smaller prime "b". If your number is exactly divisible by "a," then it is also exactly divisible by "b". Therefore you only need to check against numbers that are not lower primes.
Example: There's no point in checking the value of 4. If it is divisible by 4 it is also divisible by 2; which your loop from the bottom up you have already checked.

You increment your loop by 1 each iteration. This is overkill. You can simply start on odd number and increment by 2 (this effectively assumes 2 is a prime as the optimization). But if you want to go one step further, you can assume (2 and 3 are primes) Start on 5, jump 2, then 4, then 2, then 4, this technique effectively skips all multiples of 2 and 3.


So I would write like this:
#include <cmath>
#include <cstdint>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
int main()
{
    std::cout << "Give me a value n and I'll find you first n primes:\n";
    int n;
    std::cin >> n;

    findTheFirstNPrimes(n);
}

void findTheFirstNPrimes(int n)
{
    // Personally, I would pre-populate this with the first 1000 primes
    // as they are well known. But I suppose the is against the spirit of
    // the problem.
    std::vector<std::size_t>  primes {2, 3};

    std::size_t nextValue = 5;
    std::size_t jump = 4;
    // Note: nextValue > 5 checks for overflow.
    for (;std::size(primes) < n && nextValue >= 5; nextValue += jump)
    {
        std::size_t upperBound = std::sqrt(nextValue);
        jump = 6 - jump;                        // iterate 2/4/2/4/2/4
        bool foundNewPrime = true;
        for (auto primeCheck: primes)
        {
            if (primeCheck > upperBound) {
                break;
            }
            if (nextValue % primeCheck == 0) {
                foundNewPrime = false;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (foundNewPrime) {
            primes.emplace_back(nextValue);
        }
    }
}

Code Review
Declare control closer to the point of usage.
   bool control{ true };

It is not needed outside the loop so put it inside the loop.

Bad variable name.
    int a{ 0 };


I can forgive i it is very common loop variable, though I prefer to use something more meaningful to help readability.
    for (int i = 2; a < n; ++i)


Note: sure what the i != 2 test is for.
            if (i % x == 0 && i != 2)


It does not matter how many times control is set to false.
            {
                control = false;
            }

Once it has been set you can't go back. So may as well break out of the loop.

"Note: sure what the i != 2 test is for." It was an oversight, it's not needed, I forgot to remove it. Initially the internal loop started from 1 and this i !=2 was present.  Thank for the review and for your time.

Eratosthenes is not a name of a sieve itself, but rather of its inventor. So, please change to Sieve of Eratosthenes, or Eratosthenes' Sieve. :)

For the OP, please note the section of the Sieve of Eratosthenes wikipedia page on segmented sieves. For very large values, you need to allocate a lot of memory.

Does the language guarantee that nextValue >= 5 detects overflow, or is it dependent on an implementation or a hardware platform?

@CiaPan: Yes. See n4892: 6.8.2 Fundamental types. Paragraph 2: The range of representable values for the unsigned type is 0 to 2N −1 (inclusive); arithmetic for the unsigned type is performed modulo 2N. [Note 2: Unsigned arithmetic does not overflow.]

@LokiAstari THX! :D

Have you checked if your code really runs faster than the OP's solution?

@md2perpe: Yes. The original takes about 10 minutes to find the first 100000 primes. My version, with a few minor optimizations, takes less than a second.

How does my solution compare to your on your machine?

@md2perpe: For the first 100000 primes. My solution was 0.193s your solution takes 0m0.388s. So, my solution is about twice as fast. for this small number of primes. When I try and find 10,000,000 primes. My solution takes 13.632s and your was 1m31.377s so we are starting to diverge quickly as its now 6 times faster.

@md2perpe: Just started a run with n = 1'000'000'000; to see how long it takes on mine. Do you want to run your version see how long it takes? Been running about 30 minutes (approx) and I have the first 200'893'406 primes

Running different versions on different computers don't give comparable numbers.

@md2perpe If you time the first two version (100000,  10,000,000) on your computer we should be able to get a ratio of the difference between your hardware and mine. Then when you run the third version (1'000'000'000) we can use that ratio to give us a rough estimate. We are not timing to the nearest second (I think the closest hour will do).

@md2perpe The n = 1'000'000'000; is still running we have 736'205'299 after approx two hours (I have a feeling your version will take a couple of days to complete). In that I time I have writen Sieve of Eratosthenes with a sive size of 15'000'000'000 (compressed since I don't store even numbers that equivalent to 30'000'000'000) It took 5m5.324s to run.

15'000'000'000 sive => just under 2G of memory. But a nice size for speed exchange.

Finsihed: n = 1'000'000'000; took 177m50.601s. If I assume by this point your algorithm is only 10 times worse (which I think is being generous) It would take about a day and a quarter to complete while the Sieve takes only 5 minutes.

I recommend separating the steps for parsing input, calculating the solution, and printing output. This makes it easier to compare various algorithmic approaches. I find such an approach especially helpful for textbook exercises / LeetCode / competitive programming. Some other suggestions:

Pick the most appropriate data types. For example, I would use an unsigned type for n because it doesn't really make sense to find the first -1 primes. To be more specific, I would use size_t for n because it indicates that I can't find more primes than can be stored with std::vector.
Try to convey meaning with your variable names. You could replace x with factor, a with count, control with is_prime, etc.
Think about opportunities for optimization. You can break on the first factor in the innermost for loop. You don't need to test factors greater than sqrt(i) because if some x > sqrt(i) was a factor, you would have already found the factor i / x.

Here is an implementation using the above suggestions:
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using std::vector;
typedef unsigned long long ULL;

bool is_prime(ULL cand)
{
    if (cand < 2)
        return false;

    for (ULL factor = 2; factor * factor <= cand; ++factor)
        if (cand % factor == 0)
            return false;

    return true;
}

vector<ULL> first_n_primes(size_t n)
{
    vector<ULL> primes{};

    for (ULL cand = 2; primes.size() < n; ++cand)
        if (is_prime(cand))
            primes.push_back(cand);

    return primes;
}

int main()
{
    std::cout << "Enter an integer n >= 0 and I'll find the first n primes: ";
    size_t n;
    std::cin >> n;
    vector<ULL> primes = first_n_primes(n);
    for (const auto &prime : primes)
        std::cout << prime << ' ';
}


good idea to use unsigned long long. Thanks

This is a very good start. Keep on programming. Take my text below as encouragement.
As your program almost works (it will give correct answer for n=1, sorry I was wrong) I add some thoughts on programming in general. I give them as imperatives, but as always they are only suggestions, not any type of laws.
Find and use a good convention for naming variables. There has been many over time: camelCase, hungarian, ...  (There are wikipedia articles on this). Thinking about how to convey meaning in variable names is helps the next 200 times you read the program (we all read program code a lot more often than write it). The name control is a bit odd, maybe I would call it isPrime instead?
See if you can divide your problem into separate parts and make them into functions or procedures. You will then be able to reuse them at your next project. One example might be where you ask for an integer. Doing that as a separate function allows you to think through what to do if the user enters  eg: 0, -1, an extremely large number, some text not beeing a number. In a similar way, the listing of primes can be done into a function. Be warned though that this is sort the next step in programming experience.
Look into how you can add unit tests into your code. As example, can you make a test that sees if the prime function actually returns all primes (regardless of value of n) and only primes. A typical unit test could have one part testing if the algoritm actually checks if a number is a prime. It could have a list of tuples: n, isPrime. It could look like [0, false; 1, false; 2, true; 123456789, false]. Finding good tests to do is part of programming. Another test might see if you count the correct number of primes: how many primes will you get if n = 123456789.
Once you have a functioning program look into if you can optimize it. Here, it is quite evident that your program will take a long time to run for large values of n. One optimization you might want to do is to make it run faster. On the other hand, maybe the optimization will make the program run out of memory, your choice and only tests will show. Can you find a better algorithm (hint, see other answers). As you already have the unit tests written ;-) you can test your working algorithm against another and see if you get the same result and if it actually runs faster.
Regardless, have fun. It is fun to do programming.

Thanks for the advice, I think they are generally very useful. As for the checks I did them spot on large and small numbers for example on the order 100, 1000, 10000... when I saw that a sequence of 30...40.. values ​​were correct I took it for granted that the result was correct. The algorithm does nothing but evaluate the divisibility that there is with respect to a certain number with all its predecessors (excluding the unit, x, the smallest divisor, starts from 2) setting to false if it happens at least once...

I find the text interesting, it gives you a taste of a topic but in reality then it deals with it much further. As much as possible I am trying to stay as close as possible to the topics covered which up to this point are very limited (iterations, vectors, a hint of functions, and little else), references, pointers or other are much further ahead. I hope to get there...
Putting n = 1 the result is 2, it should be correct.

@RedM3tal  I read the code wrong, 1 gives correct answer. Only shows that the only way to test code is by running it. My personal "reocord" is a three-line program that gave the wrong result and messed up things before it was debugged.

Certainly, when I'm better I'll definitely do it, do it by hand and it's heavy..

The least you should do to improve the code is to extract the prime test to a function:
#include <iostream>

bool is_prime(int n)
{
    for (int i=2; i*i<=n; i++)
    {
        if (n % i == 0) {
            return false;
        }
    }

    return true;
}

int main()
{
    std::cout << "Give me a value n and I'll find you first n primes: ";

    int n;
    std::cin >> n;

    unsigned count = 0;
    for (int i=2; count<n; i++)
    {
        if (is_prime(i)) {
            std::cout << i << ' ';
            count++;
        }
    }
}

https://godbolt.org/z/KaEdhs5sd
In this simple case I don't see any need for more expressive variable names or a more efficient algorithm, but extracting the prime test to a function does a lot to readability.

The n = 1'000'000'000; is still running we have 736'205'299 after approx two hours (I have a feeling your version will take a couple of days to complete). In that I time I have writen Sieve of Eratosthenes with a sive size of 15'000'000'000 (compressed since I don't store even numbers that equivalent to 30'000'000'000) It took 5m5.324s to run. I think this shows algorithms are very important. Multiple days Vs 5 minutes.
